# d-heaps deletion algorithm

Tags: algorithm

> Binary heaps are so simple that they are almost always used when
>   priority queues are needed. A simple generalization is a d-heap, which
>   is exactly like a binary heap except that all nodes have d children
>   (thus, a binary heap is a 2-heap).
>
> Notice that a d-heap is much more shallow than a binary heap,
>   improving the running time of inserts to O(log( base(d)n)). However,
>   the delete_min operation is more expensive, because even though the
>   tree is shallower, the minimum of d children must be found, which
>   takes d - 1 comparisons using a standard algorithm. This raises the
>   time for this operation to O(d logdn). If d is a constant, both
>   running times are, of course, O(log n).

My question is for d childeren we should have d comparisions, how author concluded that d-1 comparisions using a standard algorithm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one comparison less than children.

E.g. for two children `a1` and `a2` you compare only once `a1<=>a2` to find the smaller one.

For three children `a1`, `a2`, `a3` you compare once to find the smaller of `a1` and `a2` and a second time to compare the smaller one to `a3`.

By induction you see that for each additional child you need an additional comparison, comparing the minimum of the previous list with the newly added child.

Thus, in general for `d` children you need `d-1` comparisons to find the minimum.